# Mobile phone models that contain 2 way radio functionality

Tags: ht, software-defined-radio

Are there any mobile phone models there that contain 2 way radio functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes indeed!](http://www.engadget.com/2013/01/15/runbo-x5-x3-x1/) Legally, you can only use these if you're a part 90 operator, or a ham, just like the Baofeng/Wouxun/Chinese radios, and the cellular side works as an unlocked phone.

Comment: Ahhh this is perfect, I was also ideally looking for one that also ran android OS!

Comment: Could you provide a link to what a "part 90 operator" is?

Answer (score 5):

The smarmy answer is of course, that cell phones *are* two way radios on either the 800Mhz band (Sprint & US Cellular) or the 1900MHz band (all the others).  Not what you meant, I know.  The old Nextel phones with their "push-to-talk" feature were two-way radios using the old 50 MHz taxi-dispatcher band.  Later versions of this technology used 900MHz.

I found a couple of references to cell phones that incorporate what looks like FRS service in the 446 MHz band with a claimed range of 5km (http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/693379680/Cell_Phone_Two_Way_Radio.html is an example).